# How to set the dependency value

Tags: wpf

I have some control like

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding tests, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}" />
```

When user cliked on some element of the ListBox I needed to get data element of this ListBoxItem element in other control and propagate it with data template of other element. How do it properly? Example:

Source:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding tests, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}" />
```

Target:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
```

Where Text in TextBox bind on same data element of selected ListBox item

**UPDATE:**
How make some control whose content bind to SelectedItem and described by static data template like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Resolve with:**

```
 <ContentPresenter
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=tests_flat, Path=SelectedItem}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TestInfoTemplate}">
                </ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding tests, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}" />
```

Target

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myListBox path=SelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: ok, and one answer: How make data template to this binding as static resource?

Answer (score 1):

You could either bind directly to the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property (if your items are strings) or set the [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) of your ListBox and bind to the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) property.